# Selenium automation on Oracle applications

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, tools, test-strategy

Is there a way we can perform `Selenium automation` (with `Java`) on `Oracle` applications?

On the `Oracle website` they have given ways by which we can convert the `Oracle applications` into `Oracle ADF` faces applications and then automate it with `Selenium` or the `Oracle application` can be converted into a webpage and then it can be automated.

But instead of these two methods is there any other way anyone has tried?

I don't want to use other testing tools like `QTP`, `Oracle ATS` or `Windows` (which is an open source tool). So in spite of all this, is there still a way through which `Selenium automation` can be done on `Oracle applications`?

Comment: Did you ask to test non-webapplication with web browser?

Comment: No. I'm asking if oracle applications which is a non web application be tested by selenium through some way.

Comment: Read the Selenium FAQ about Selenium and Webdriver - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions    WebDriver is a tool for writing automated tests of websites. It aims to mimic the behaviour of a real user, and as such interacts with the HTML of the application.  Selenium works by injecting javascript into the browser - hence it's used for testing web apps

Comment: yes, i know it cannot be used on desktop applications. but what I'm asking is, if there is some one out there who has implemented selenium automation on oracle applications because I heard that some people have some how did it.according to my experience its not possible to do the automation but now that there are people who say that they have done it, i'm begining to think maybe there is something i don't know about, that why i posted this question

Comment: ok, i found one way, if the front end of the oracle applications is a webpage then selenium can be used. if the front end is oracle forms then it cannot be used.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: I am Jasmine, I had the same requirement with you. My company is using Oracle EBiz R12. Before moved to open source, we used QTP. So now we use Selenium IDE to handle web-based UI such as the login page and the Oracle responsibility selection page through Java. For Oracle forms, we choose Sikuli. I just started to explore, couldn't share much. We use Eclipse to write our script. I am hope to have you working on the same requirement so that we could share more when we face any challenges. Jasmine

Comment: Welcome to SQA Jasmine. Unfortunately this isn't an answer to the question and as such should probably be removed. Me too answers don't add any value. If this question is important to you, try favoriting it. If you have a slightly different question that does not get answered here I suggest creating a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only test HTML based websites with Selenium.  If the Oracle application exposes an HTML based front end that is accessible via a web browser then you can use Selenium to test it, if not you can't.

You may want to have a look at native driver:

http://code.google.com/p/nativedriver/

This is based on WebDriver and aims to expand the automation capabilities to desktop applications (I'm not sure how active it is at the moment though).

Answer (score 4):

If your question is, **"Can I test desktop application with Selenium?"**, the simple answer would be **NO.**

Selenium is a Javascript based framework (Javascript is implemented into web browsers) which means that it can interact only with web page elements.

Comment: yes, i know it cannot be used on desktop applications. but what I'm asking is, if there is some one out there who has implemented selenium automation on oracle applications because I heard that  some people have some how did it.

Comment: @Tom, maybe I misunderstand but what exactly you mean by saying "oracle applications". Did you mean specific product?

Comment: Tom, perhaps you could ask for clarification from whoever told you that some people have somehow done it.

Comment: @xeranas: this is about oracle application. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Applications

Comment: @user246: yes, i will be communicating with that team next week but in the mean time i just wanted to know if at all some one has done selenium automation on oracle apps. according to my experience its not possible to do the automation but now that there a set of people who say that they have done it, i'm begining to think maybe there is something i don't know abt, that why i posted this question.

Comment: @top, your wikipedia link talks about applications (not specific one) from Oracle company. This company have many applications and you trying to say that you want test ALL applications which owns Oracle?